# How to recognize which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, dynamic

I am using wordpress for my blog posts - all posts are fetched on the same page and each post has button, I need to be able to recognise which button of which post was clicked.

I can do it only with hardcoded data, but I am unsuccessful with dynamic ones.

I tried to give a trigger button common class and then detect it in JS.

```
<div class="row"> 
     <button class="common-button-class">CLICK</button>
</div>

let openButton = document.getElementsByClassName(
    'common-button-class'
);


if (openButton != null) {
            document.querySelector('.common-button-class')
            .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            // tried detect event id here unsuccessfully 
});
   }
```

Is there function of how to know which post is being triggered?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.common-button-class').addEventListener` will only add a click handler to the first element with that class.

Comment: You could simply specify the post id as the `value` of your button, then you just need to read that attribute inside your click handler.

Comment: I did `<button value="<?php the_ID(); ?>">` and tried to `alert(event.getAttribute(value))`, but button is not getting triggered at all.

Comment: The button element has the value, not the event.

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` instaid of `getElementsByClassName`

```
let openButton = document.querySelector('.common-button-class');
openButton.onclick = function() {
    //Your code here
};
```

Comment: thank you @migtarx, but did not really do anything

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery in WordPress

first add properties just like `data-id` and keep post id in it.
then :

```
 $(document).on("click",".common-button-class", function () {
     var clickedBtnID = $(this).data('id'); 
     alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedBtnID);
 });
```

Comment: I think this similar approach I tried, but unfortunately it does not fire at all for some reason.

Comment: yes is has similar logic to what you are trying to do, but you attempt to use javascript and it is its jquery version of that. there can be various reasons that prevent your code from running successfully and at top of them, we have a kind of js conflicts/errors/loading issues. if we want to figure out where is the problem exactly we must try other approaches and then look back for the previous situation. anyway, just copy this answer in your console tab and check if it works or not.

Comment: I found the reason why it was not triggered, I just had to replace all `$` and write `jQuery` instead

Comment: good, so most probably some script loaded `.noConflict()` . this must be the reason that it doesn't worked before.